# How to add a libgcc.a library to my keil project

Tags: c, gcc, ld, cortex-m

I need to make a library for a customer who is using GCC. I have a working Keil project compiled with the GCC. The next step is to make a library. I removed from the project main file and Keil generated libname.a library file. Now I want to create a new project with the same main and libname.a library. I'm failing to do so. I added this library to Options/Linker tab, added library path and getting "c:/gnu arm embedded toolchain/10p3_2021_10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibname.a
Here is all the options/flags:

-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -o ./DebugConfig/name_main.elf -L ./DebugConfig *.o -llibname.a -mcpu=cortex-m4 --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -static -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--end-group --specs=nano.specs -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you put `libname.a` in a _separate_ project from your main project, you need to tell the main project what directory has the `.a`. (e.g.) With `/home/me/projects/main` and `/home/me/projects/mylib`, the main project needs `-L ../mylib` before `-llibname.a`. But, if the library is (e.g.) `libxyz.a`, then the options are: `-L ../mylib -lxyz`. Or, `../mylib/libxyz.a`. Note that for the `-l` option with a library `libXXX.a` you want: `-lXXX` and _not_ `-llibXXX` or `-llibXXX.a`

Comment: I am not sure if there is a mistake in your post: "who is using gcc" suggests that the customer is using gcc ("who" can only refer to a person) if this is the case and the customer uses gcc then they can use their version of libgcc when they link the final application, you do not have to include it in the library.  If you mean that the library is compiled with gcc, then perhaps you could edit the post to say "which uses gcc" or "which is compiled with gcc".

Comment: @TomV. My customer is using GCC, therefore I also have to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had made a mistake in your English.  If the customer is using gcc then you should let them do thin linking, otherwise you will waste space and maybe create other problems by having two copies of the library.

Comment: @TomV The only thing customer should do is to pay for my job, the rest is my responsibility.

Comment: I have worked in consultancy for years.  The customer is paying you to tell them the right way to do it.  If they are already including a copy of libgcc and you include a second copy then you are doing it wrong and they should not pay you at all.

Comment: @TomV There is no white and black, it always shades of gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed is to put a colon in front of the name **:libname.a** ...

I hate fighting with tools.
Here is the solution: I need to add into the misc section separately -L path\lib\one   -l libname
Or -l:name.a

I did not find where it is written that my options are:

1. -l name    and in this case libname.a file will be searched for;
2. -l:name.a  and in this case    name.a file is the target library.

Why does it have to be so convoluted and complicated... This is just a rhetorical question, obviously. I hope this will help someone else in the future.